# Play video in Firemonkey on Windows XP

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I use `TMediaPlayerControl` to show video in my application.

This is my code to show video:

```
TrailerMediaPlayer.FileName := GetcurrentDir + '\Trailer\Trailer.avi';
if (TrailerMediaPlayer.State = TMediaState.Stopped) and
  (TrailerMediaPlayer.CurrentTime < TrailerMediaPlayer.Duration) then
begin
  TrailerMediaPlayer.Play;
  PositionTrackBar.Max := TrailerMediaPlayer.Duration;
end
else
begin
  TrailerMediaPlayer.CurrentTime := 0;
end;
```

It works on Windows 7/8, but in Windows XP I get `unsupported media file` error!

Note that Windows Media Player plays my Trailer.avi in Windows XP.

How can I play this video on every Windows OS (since XP) without any extra components?

Comment: You did not say what codec your video is

Comment: My video is uncompressed avi. I tried this for windows 7 sample video, but it's not worked too.(Wildlife.wmv)

Answer (score 0):

Get [madexcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm), or any other similar tool and post the stack of the application. Also, this should be a problem with codecs and other applications installed on the machine, even the movie is played in XP's Windows Media Player.

As several suggestions : use the Windows Media Player ActiveX or the [ActiveX plugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/Delphi) from VideoLan.

Also be sure to follow this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayerControl and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Building_a_Basic_Media_Player

PS: Be aware that FireMonkey is not VCL - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Converting_from_VCL_to_FireMonkey and do not mix these two. (I'm just suspecting you're doing it, so without the code I can not be sure of it...)

Comment: I do everything in [this article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Building_a_Basic_Media_Player), but in a new Windows XP (without any codec) application throws an exception that is the media file not supported, however Media Player played it!!!

Comment: even I don't like those exclamation marks, can you post a small example of what you've done and the stack of the exception as I suggested you to do in the answer?

Comment: I have no more important code. The code in my question is in `PlayButtonClick` event and it works on my Windows 8.